# При записи в файл excel тратится память

Tags: java, excel, память

Есть метод для записи в файл структуры данных на `java`.
Структура - `FinishFile - List<String[]>`.
Записывается структура довольно большая: около 200000 массивов по 12 ячеек. В итоге все кончается.

> Exception in thread "Thread-3" java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: GC overhead limit exceeded

```
private void write(String PATH, String filename, int masCount) {
    XSSFCellStyle net = null;
    try {
        InputStream inp = new FileInputStream(PATH + filename);
        Workbook wb = null;
        try {
            wb = WorkbookFactory.create(0);
            net = (XSSFCellStyle) wb.createCellStyle();
            net.setBorderLeft(BorderStyle.THIN);
            net.setBorderRight(BorderStyle.THIN);
            net.setBorderTop(BorderStyle.THIN);
            net.setBorderBottom(BorderStyle.THIN);
        } catch (EncryptedDocumentException | InvalidFormatException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        Sheet sheet = wb.getSheetAt(0);
        int rowCounter = 0;
        Cell[] mas = new Cell[masCount];
        Cell[] cellList = new Cell[masCount]; // masCount - число столбцов
        for (int i = 0; i < getFinishFile().size(); i++) {
            Row row = sheet.createRow(rowCounter++);
            for (int j = 0; j < mas.length; j++) {
                mas[j] = row.createCell(j);
                cellList[j] = mas[j];
                cellList[j].setCellValue(getFinishFile().get(i)[j]); 
                cellList[j].setCellStyle(net);
            }
        }
        FileOutputStream fileOut = new FileOutputStream(PATH + filename);
        wb.write(fileOut);
        fileOut.close();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если вы работаете с большими структурами данных, то стоит увеличить размер Heap. Попробуйте указать в параметрах JVM максимальный размер Heap, например, -Xmx1024m.

Comment: тут 2 ГБ стоит уже) нужно по другому как то

Comment: [Здесь](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1393486/error-java-lang-outofmemoryerror-gc-overhead-limit-exceeded) вы можете найти описание ошибки и советы по её устранению.